# How to get the next command id to use when inserting a MenuItem?

Tags: c++, windows, explorer

I implement `IContextMenu2` and want to populate the menu when its being hovered over. In `QueryContextMenu` I get the argument `idCmdFirst`. In `HandleMenuMsg2`, however, i dont get this argument. Therefore, what do i pass to `InsertMenu` for the id parameter?

Comment: Please paste your code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically stored the `idCmdFirst` from `QueryContextMenu` and used it in `HandleMenuMsg2`.

Comment: Make sure you don't use any values you didn't already reserve by the return value from your `QueryContextMenu`, because they may have been reassigned to some other context menu extension.